# Wordpress get user id by email

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to look up a user id by the email address they created their account with. Normally I would use:

```
<?php $user_ID = get_current_user_id(); ?>
```

But in this case, the user has not been signed in yet.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Found a quick way to do it:

```
$user = get_user_by( 'email', 'user@example.com' );
$userId = $user->ID;
```